# Why is $\int_0^{{9\pi}\over{4}}{1 \over |\sin x|+|\cos x| }dx~ = ~9\int_0^{{\pi}\over{4}}{1 \over |\sin x|+|\cos x| }dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^{{9\pi}\over{4}}{1 \over |\sin x|+|\cos x| }dx~ = ~9\int_0^{{\pi}\over{4}}{1 \over |\sin x|+|\cos x| }dx$$

$ 1 \over |\sin x|+|\cos x|  $ is $\pi \over 2$ periodic so 
$$\int_0^{{9\pi}\over{4}}{1 \over |\sin x|+|\cos x| }dx~ = ~4\int_0^{{\pi}\over{2}}{1 \over |\sin x|+|\cos x| }dx~+~\int_{2\pi}^{{9\pi}\over{4}}{1 \over |\sin x|+|\cos x| }dx~$$

I don't see how to transfrom this to the desired integral, I suppose this isn't the right way to start.

Comment: This isn't a direct integral transformation. The point is that the integral over $[0, \pi/4]$ is equal to the integral over $[\pi/4, \pi/2]$ (and then periodicity gives you the rest). To see this equality, you should appeal to symmetry. I drew a picture. Alternately, you can do a substitution $x \mapsto \pi/2 - x$ and recognize that $\sin$ and $\cos$ switch places.

Comment: The function is also symmetric about $x=\pi/4$.

Comment: @user how to see that

Comment: @davidlowryduda What does the substitution $x:=\pi /2 -x$ show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

The function has a symmetry about $x=\frac\pi4$, i.e. $f(x)=f\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)$:
$$\left|\sin\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)\right|+\left|\cos\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)\right|=|\cos x|+|\sin x|.$$

Comment: Doesn't this argument show function is symmetric around $\pi \over 2$ not $\pi \over 4$

Comment: No. It shows the symmetry around $\frac\pi4$. The symmetry around $\frac\pi2$ would be demonstrated by $f(\pi-x)=f(x)$, which is of course also true.

Comment: I see because $f(x)=f\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)$ implies $f(\frac\pi4 -x)=f\left(\frac\pi4+x\right)$

Comment: @Milan Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** see the area under the $\Gamma_f$ on the figure below.

[image: see Figure]

Comment: lako je tako :)

Comment: treba znati i ovako ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Idea**

Observe that $|\sin x+|\cos x|$ is equal to one of the following (depending on the signs taken in various intervals) $\pm \sin x \pm \cos x=\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x\pm \frac{\pi}{4}\right) \text{ or } \sqrt{2}\cos\left(x\pm \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$.